Why is my list index out of range in this for loop?
I've been tasked to write a program that receives user input and then outputs the input but without any vowels.
I have this code:
text = str(input("Input: ")).strip()

# find positions of vowels

vow_pos = []
vowels = ["A","a","E","e","I","i","O","o","U","u"]
k = 0
for i in range(len(text)):
    for k in range(len(vowels)):
        if text[i].find(vowels[k]) != -1:
            vow_pos.append(i)
        k = k + 1

# delete vowels based on position
for j in range(len(vow_pos)):
    if j > 0:
        vow_pos[j] = vow_pos[j] - j
        text = text.replace(text[vow_pos[j]],"") # <-(Line giving error)
    else:
        text = text.replace(text[vow_pos[j]],"")


print("Output: " + str(text))

But I get an error at the marked line which says IndexError: list index out of range.
Initially, I didn't take into account that upon one character being deleted, the length of the overall string would then also decrease by 1. However, I'm trying to account for that with the vow_pos[j] = vow_pos[j] - j code. It still seems to give an error after 5 or so vowels.
What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug" - it's your responsibility to trace through what happens as the code actually runs, not just try to check your own logic on paper. This is the same problem as in English class; you can't proofread by saying what you think the text says, you have to check what is actually there. Please read How to debug small programs and What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?.

So, try going through the code step by step, with the actually results. You already figured out, I guess, what you expect to be the value of text at the start of each j loop, for some suitably complex input. and the value of vow_pos, and therefore what result you expect to get from vow_pos[j], and thus text[vow_pos[j]]. The next step is to check that.

But if you actually just want to know "how do I remove characters from a string at multiple specific indices, all at once?", that is a completely separate question and it's better off a) searched for first and b) asked with a specification rather than code to debug. (And if you just want to "filter" characters out of the original string if they match a certain condition - such as "being a vowel" - that can be done far more directly, and is also a separate how-to question.)

Finally: for future questions please read [ask] and the [tour], and note well that this is not a discussion forum. I edited the post to show good style for asking here. We don't want personal context or background; we want a clear explanation of a problem, and a directly asked question about that problem.

@Karl, despite your assertions, it is often a great help to questioners to ask "find the bug" questions provided the answers have a proper explanation of what they're doing wrong. In any case, OP did do proper analysis on their code as evidenced by the final few paragraphs, so I don't consider it an attempt to just get someone to do their work for them. You should keep in mind that not everyone here is at the same level of expertise.

And, if the assumption that you down-voted all the answers is correct, I also disagree with that. The answers can be helpful regardless of the question. The right thing in that case would have been to close-vote the question rather than down-vote valid answers.

@paxdiablo Please read: Why should I help close "bad" questions that I think are valid, instead of helping the OP with an answer? It has nothing to do with expertise or perceived laziness or anything else. It has to do with the suitability of questions for the format and the purpose of the site, as described in the [tour] and on Meta. I did also vote to close. But answers to questions that should be closed, I find inherently not useful and in fact damaging.

@Karl, I read that first post, I just disagree with it :-). While it is a valid opinion of yours (and many answers there seem to agree), it actually goes against the "ask about/don't ask about" sections of the (more official) FAQ, primarily "ask about specific programming problems" and "don't ask questions where you haven't tried yourself)". This particular question seems to be valid based on those items at least. We've both stated our positions and I'm not certain either of us will change so we can probably move this to chat if you wish to continue ...

for k in range(len(vowels)):
    :
    k = k + 1

For a start, the for loop itself iterates k correctly, you should not be adjusting it manually within the loop body.
Second, your manipulation of the vowel positions is almost certainly problematic. Rather than fixing it, there are better ways to strip out vowels that don't involve storing the positions, something like (if you still want an explicit loop):
vowelled = str(input("Input: ")).strip()

# transfer all but vowels
vowels = ["A","a","E","e","I","i","O","o","U","u"]
text = ""
for char in vowelled:
    if char not in vowels:
        text += char
print("Output: " + str(text))

A more Pythonic way is to use a list comprehension:
text = "".join([char for char in vowelled if char not in vowels])


I was going to really emphasize that the OP's code is extremely un-pythonic.  It's hard to learn all the ways to do things pythonic-ly, but it's why you'd use python.  Definitely look into list/set/dict comprehensions, x in Xs syntax, and enumerate to reduce the complexity of your code.  That "".join(<list comprehension>) is also more efficient because strings are immutable in python and editing them in a for-loop is going to be slow and is poor memory use.

I think you're complicating things, consider an easier way when writing in Python. This way it is not necessary to play with the position in the arrays.
# Ask for the input text
text = input("Input: ").strip()

# Define the set of the vowels
vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu"

# Concatenate (a non-space with the letter) only if this is not in vowels
result = ''.join([char for char in text if char not in vowels])

# Print the result
print("Output: " + result)

